# Magento - Admin view orders error

Tags: magento

Within the admin section when clicking to view an order we're getting the following error:

There has been an error processing your request

```
Invalid method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_History::isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable(Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Pending
            [notified] => 0
            [comment] => 
            [created_at] => Zend_Date Object
                (
                    [_locale:Zend_Date:private] => en_GB
                    [_fractional:Zend_Date:private] => 0
                    [_precision:Zend_Date:private] => 3
                    [_unixTimestamp:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => 1321280177
                    [_timezone:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => Europe/London
                    [_offset:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => -3600
                    [_syncronised:Zend_Date_DateObject:private] => 0
                    [_dst:protected] => 1
                )

        )

)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we copied in fresh code files from 1.6.1 and copied them into our path. It all seemed to work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like the default exception of `Varien_Object::__call()`, which is raised whenever you try to call an unknown method of an `Varien_Object` instance.

Either you completely missed to define an `isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable` method in the appropriate class, or the spellings of the defined and the called method do mismatch.

To identify the class causing the exception, I'd append the output of `mageDebugBacktrace()` in the `throw` instruction of `Varien_Object::__call()`.

If you get no backtrace output, the exception is probably thrown in a class extending `Varien_Object` *and* overriding the `__call()` method. In that case scan your code for `function __call(` matches and append the `mageDebugBacktrace()` output in the found method.